# Distance between current and previous GPS Point BigQuery

Tags: sql, distance, gps

I have a table with 150.000 rows containing DateTime, GpsLongitude and GpsLatitude columns. Timestamp difference between rows is 10 seconds. I want to calculate the distance between every current and previous GPS point (so the distance in meters between GPS points every 10 seconds).

I tried with the query below:

```
select DateTime, 
ST_DISTANCE(PointWKT1, LAG(PointWKT1) OVER (PARTITION BY DateTime ORDER BY DateTime)) as distance
from (select DateTime, ST_GEOGPOINT(GpsLongitude, GpsLatitude) as PointWKT1
      FROM `xxx.yyy` )
      order by DateTime
```

The problem is, that the returned *distance* is always null! Any suggections what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Remove `PARTITION BY DateTime` from `OVER` clause.

`Partition by` clause splits input into independent partitions, and then computation is performed for each partition independently. It might be useful if you have many independent tracks, e.g. different users, and want to partition by user id. Here you want computation over whole dataset - so `OVER(ORDER BY DateTime)` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful!